# Computing limit from the right of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I'm trying to show that
$$\lim_{x \to 1_+} \frac{\frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{1}{x-1}}e^{-\frac{1}{x-2}}}-1}{t-1} = 1$$
I tried rewriting it as
$$\lim_{t \to 1_+}  \frac{-e^{-\frac{1}{t-1}}e^{-\frac{1}{t-2}} }{(t-1)(1+e^{-\frac{1}{t-1}}e^{-\frac{1}{t-2}})} = \lim_{t \to 1_+}  \frac{-e^{-\frac{1}{t-1}}e}{e^{-\frac{1}{t-1}}e - e^{-\frac{1}{t-1}}e    } = \lim_{t \to 1_+} \frac{-1}{1-1}$$
But this results in $-\frac{1}{0}$ which of course is not what I'm looking for. Any help would be great